# I can't Fetch Data into My Datatable in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I want to Fetch Data into My Datatable I'm getting THis Error: ***undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.articles.map')***

### This is the Code if Someone can help me :

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, ScrollView,Text, View, Modal } from 'react-native';
import { DataTable } from 'react-native-paper';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import COLORS from '../src/conts/colors';
import Button from '../src/views/components/Button';


const List = ({navigation}) => {



     const [data,setData] = useState([])
     const [loading,setLoading]= useState(true)


     const fetchData = ()=>{
        fetch("https://flow.simpas.ai/hortus/paysagiste/category?businessid=0899607494")
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(results=>{

            setData(results)
            setLoading(false)


        })
     }

     useEffect(()=>{
          fetchData()
     },[])


const RenderCollection = ({item}) =>{

    return(

      <DataTable.Row style={styles.tableRow} key={item.businessid}>
            <DataTable.Cell textStyle={{color: '#777777',fontFamily: 'Roboto'}} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Edit",{item})} >{item.title}</DataTable.Cell>
            <DataTable.Cell textStyle={{color: '#FEB296', fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}>{item.title}</DataTable.Cell>
            <DataTable.Cell textStyle={{color: '#777777', fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}>{item.price}</DataTable.Cell>
        </DataTable.Row>
    )
  }
return (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1}}>
  <ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{paddingTop: 50, paddingHorizontal: 20}}>
    <Text style={{color: COLORS.black, fontSize: 40, fontWeight: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Roboto',textAlign: 'center'}}>
      List of Companies
    </Text>
    <Text style={{color: COLORS.grey, fontSize: 18, marginVertical: 10, fontFamily: 'Roboto', textAlign: 'center'}}>
      Check Our Companies Details
    </Text>
  <DataTable style={styles.container}   >
  <DataTable.Header style={styles.tableHeader}  >
    <DataTable.Title textStyle={{color: '#fff',fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}>BusinessId</DataTable.Title>
    <DataTable.Title textStyle={{color: '#fff',fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}>Title</DataTable.Title>
    <DataTable.Title textStyle={{color: '#fff',fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}>Price</DataTable.Title>
  </DataTable.Header>
  </DataTable>
  {
      data && data.articles.map(article => <RenderCollection item={article} />)
    }
  </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>

);
};

export default List;
```

### This is The Error:

Cannot read properties of undefined ('map')

### This is the Website That I'm Fetching From:

[Here](https://flow.simpas.ai/hortus/paysagiste/category?businessid=0899607494)

And Thank you to everyone Will try to help me

Answer (score 0):

async function

```
  const fetchData = async()=>{
     try{
      const res = await 
       fetch("https://flow.simpas.ai/hortus/paysagiste/category? 
       businessid=0899607494")
      const data = await res.json()
       setData(results)
       setLoading(false)
     }catch(error){
            setLoading(false)
            console.log(error)
     }

     }
```

Comment: His call is already ok, he setState after then(). But he doesn't catch the possible empty data and the loading time.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make the fetchData function asynchronous, or else the await fetch method will not work. You might also have to use the JSON.parse(data) function to make your data retrievable from where it's being store. Try doing this:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const fetch = await fetch("https://flow.simpas.ai/hortus/paysagiste/category?businessid=0899607494")
  const response = await fetch.text();
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(response);
  setData(parsedData);
  setLoading(false);
```

This worked for me in the real estate website I made, for some reason the JSON data was returned undefined, and the JSON.parse() method really helped clean it up and make it accessible.

Answer (score 0):

First, i highly reccommand you to use `<Flatlist/>` to map data. You will access to empty state method rendering when data is empty, loading state rendering to manage loading time during fetch and normal rendering when data is set.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Second, you do not really check and shield your data. `data` should be define but is maybe not an array. `articles` may have no data, etc...

This is a check i often use : `Array.isArray(data?.articles) && data?.articles.length > 0` , but i use it in React.js app, not with ReactNative, because **ReactNative get magic Flatlist ;)**.

So your example become :

```js
  <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => <RenderCollection key={index} item={item}/>}
        ListEmptyComponent={() => <Text>oops...</Text>}
   />
```